# Good low-rate, short-length block codes

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

I am highly unsure whether this question is appropriate for this site (as it is at no point a math problem), yet searching in the stackexchange universe for similar topics showed the most hits on math. So forgive me, if I'm mistaken ;)

My problem is rather simple at first sight, yet finding the answer proved rather difficult:

I am looking for low rate block codes (i.e. $R < \frac 12$, e.g. $R = 0.25$ or $R = 0.33$) with short block lengths ($n < 1000$). The codes should obviously be as good as possible.
Now here is the problem: I used to use LDPC codes, but I don't have any good degree distributions which I could take as a basis (since the LDPCOpt tool of http://ipgdemos.epfl.ch/ldpcopt/ isn't working anymore). And performing such optimizations would be too long.

I have been looking quite some time, but I didn't find anything. Any ideas? Note that I'm only looking for block codes, convolutional or turbo codes are no option.

Comment: "My problem is rather simple at first sight": you are not lacking humor...

Comment: Velcome to the site! This question is clearly on-topic here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ;) Well, what I meant was: Finding the BEST  is obviously close to impossible, but a reasonably well performing one would already be acceptable for me.

Comment: Well, a turbo code is a block code, but I guess you want an LDPC code. This may be too short for LDPC, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: You need to state what you mean by "good". High relative minimum distance? Good under soft decision / hard decision? What channel is the code going to be used on?